# How can I send a form by email with titanium

Tags: forms, email, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have seen the email dialog example and also the email dialog example, but I am not looking for an email client interface.

I also took a look at the pizza ordering app, and I couldn't find any method for the send button.

I have custom text fields and in the end I want to send the whole form to an email recipient. I can't find the way to do that.

That is, I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

For sending E-mail from your app , you have these options :-

**1-** Using `Titanium.UI.EmailDialog` .

The Email Dialog is created with the Titanium.UI.createEmailDialog method. The user needs to register an e-mail account on the device in order to open the dialog. The dialog will not open when there is not a registered e-mail account.

Ex : Android

[image]

Read more http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.EmailDialog

But As you said you don`t want like this ! and if you want to send direct messages from your app   please see these other options :-

**2-** Make any backend service like #PHP to send email 
for ex:- http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp, and using  [Titanium.Network.HTTPClient](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient)  to connect with your  backend service .

**3-** Using [ArrowDB](https://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/api/Emails)

Enjoy !

Comment: Second the use of ArrowDB, it has an EmailTemplate API making it super easy to pass some data to an API and have it sent as a nicely formatted email. This is especially helpful if you are parsing the emails

Comment: You are right, but ArrowDB required team license :)

Comment: One other thing. As already noted the above example assumes a default email account is setup for the device. If the user is using a secondary client, like Inbox or Airmail, then it will break your flow. Another reason to leverage ArrowDB, consistency of workflow

Comment: It does require a team license currently you are correct. However in this blog post you can see that is going to change ...  http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/02/your-very-own-mbaas-how-to-move-from-parse-to-appcelerator-arrow/

Comment: I hope that #ArrowDB is a powerfull tool

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps,

1) Create webservice method to send email.

2) Call particular email method in the button click.

**Note :**
[Apple](http://apple.com) will not approve if you don't provide valid reason to send email via webservice. They might think you are trying to spam users.

Answer (score 0):

You can not check this on emulator/simulator only can check on device. And in device you need to configure any email account like gmail or outlook mail.

```
 var emailDialog = Ti.UI.createEmailDialog();
 emailDialog.subject = "Hello from Titanium";
 emailDialog.toRecipients = ['foo@yahoo.com'];
 emailDialog.messageBody = '<b>Appcelerator Titanium Rocks!</b>';
 var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile('cricket.wav');
 emailDialog.addAttachment(f);
 emailDialog.open();
```

Comment: You can not check this on iOS, but you can check it on Android emulators

Answer (score 0):

Create a web service (e.g. a PHP script) that receives POST data and send an email based on it.

In your app, clicking the button simply collects all the data and POST it to your web service.